# Word Blue Line Grammar Check

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check, grammar

I typed an industry phrase that MS Word flagged in blue and wants me to put a hyphen between. It would be wrong if I did that. I know my option is to disable grammar check. So here are my questions:

1) Would that disable grammar check for all documents? I don't really want to do that.

2) If I send the document to someone who has the grammar check on, would the blue line appear?

Comment: " typed a industry phrase" ... 1) what was the phrase? 2) You need grammar-check on; your opening sentence tells us that is vital.

Comment: Your settings have no effect on the document once it reaches someone else's desk. Their own grammar settings then control what they see as far as grammar and style are concerned.

If you don't want them to see proofing marks for this document, then perhaps sending them a PDF or XPS is a better option for you.

Answer (score 0):

Word has an option to Hide Grammar and/or Hide Spelling errors in a document. The settings are at the bottom of the Options > Proofing dialog. The settings are document specific, they stay with the document and thus errors that are contained within the document, will not display on other systems.

[image]